# How to set the loadout's default weapon to dual wield?

Tags: max-payne-3

In my custom loadout I have two single handed weapons (pistol and an uzi). Every time I spawn I need to manually change to dual wielding, something that is quite cumbersome to do on the console.

How can I set it so it defaults to dual wield on spawn? I am playing on Xbox 360, so please indicate if you can only do it on PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method on the Xbox 360 to change your default weapon(s). The game tends to switch you back to a pistol or single weapon. You only need to use the radial dial to switch back to the dual wield.